# Hard coding month and year based on current month

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a login page after login based on current month and year i have to show a label like if the month is october it should appear like July-Dec 2012 and if it is january it should appear like january-june 2013 how can i do it?

Comment: The only thing I know about what you are asking is that you are definitely *not* talking about 'hard-coding' here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is ur aspx code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Label ID="datelabel" runat="server" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is ur c# code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;    // display format: 4/25/2008 11:45:44 AM
            int mon = date.Month;
            if (mon < 6)
            {
                datelabel.Text = "Jan-june" +date.Year;
            }
            else
                datelabel.Text = "july-dec" +date.Year;

        }
```

Comment: No, Desired output should be 'July-Dec 2012' and 'january-june 2013'.

Comment: @Xavier, your profile states that you're 23yo, so why are you still writing like a teenager?  :-) "ur" is _not_ a word (in English, anyway).

Comment: @paxdiablo I'm sorry.. As i got used to the my mobile chat i used like that.. Will try to avoid that in future..:)

Answer (score 2):

Provided you can get the current date somehow (a given, I would say), simply code up something like the following pseudo-code:

```
today = now()                              // Current date
if today.month() < 6:                      // Assumes months 0-based.
    output = "January-June " + today.year()
else:
    output = "July-December " + today.year()
```

Comment: May be i can get current date like this DateTime.Now.ToString()

Comment: @Newbie - `DateTime.Now.Month` will return an integer representation of the current month (1-based).

Comment: No, Desired output should be 'July-Dec 2012' and 'january-june 2013'

Comment: What's your point, @Prasad? Are you suggesting that Jan 2012 should result in "Jan-Jun 2013"? I can't see a use case for that.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yes, Correct. That is what newbie required.. in his post

Comment: No, OP said "if it is january it should appear like january-june 2013" - they did not specify that the current year was 2012, so the most logical conclusion is that the January being talked about is next January. In other words, OP wants which half of the year it is in the _current_ year. Any other suggestion seems to imply that the OP is a raving lunatic which I'm pretty certain isn't the case.

Comment: Agreed with @paxdiablo. That's what I also get from the question. Newbie should have made it clear though.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
        var today = DateTime.Now;
        var result = today.Month <= 6
                         ? string.Format("January-June {0}", today.AddYears(1).Year)
                         : string.Format("July-December  {0}", today.Year);
```

**Result**: July-December  2012

Comment: Why do you convert `DateTime.Now` to a string and then immediately back to a `DateTime`?  Also, `DateTime`'s `.Month` [is 1-based](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month.aspx), not 0-based, so `today.Month < 6` cuts off June.

Comment: @James D'Angelo --- Comment from Newbie: May be i can get current date like this DateTime.Now.ToString() – Newbie

Comment: Just because @Newbie made the comment, doesn't mean it's right. No reason to have it in your answer.

Comment: No problem, but you still have the issue of .NET's Month being 1-based, not 0-based.